# ID already Exist vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a code where I want it to update my table and check if there is EmployeeID that is already existing as well. [In this picture, I already create a sample EmployeeID but whenever I want it to update,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLdF8.png) [the message box Employee ID already exist interfere. I tried a lot of codes but being a beginner makes it hard for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLHy9.png) this is my code to the button Update: Any Help would be Appreciated thank you!

```
Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        If tbxFname.Text = "" Or tbxLname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter required fields!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connString)
            connection.Open()
            Dim com As New SqlCommand("select * FROM [EmmeSubic].[dbo].[UserDetails] WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID", connection)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", tbxEmployeeId.Text)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("Employee Id is Already Exist!!")
            Else
                connection.Close()
                db.SaveChanges()
                MessageBox.Show("Your Update has been Saved Successfully!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub`
```

Comment: I can't see an UPDATE command!? If you want to update an existing entry the EmpleeID must be there. So your current SELECT can only be used to verify that the entry exits and then perform the update.

Comment: so, should I query an update to the else then? how

Comment: Instead of the MsgBox "...already exits" you'll have to create an UPDATE command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is insert a new record, add a new employee. When you say Update, we think you are referring to updating an existing record, changing the data for an existing employee. You need to set up EmployeeID as the Primary Key of the UserDetails table. It should be set up as an identity field that will auto-increment. Then you will not include the EmployeeID in the Insert statement. The database will provide a new value for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to have a look at your database. Be sure primary key is set.

Comment: primary is set to Id but EmployeeID is what I am trying to use as an validation for the existing or upcoming changes

Comment: @KennethCastro You mean there is a field called Id, the Primary Key, and another field called EmployeeID, not the primary key? You need to Update by Primary Key.